Pandas - groupby string field and select by time-of-day range
I have a dataset like this
index   Date_Time   Pass_ID El
0   3/30/23 05:12:36.36 A   1
1   3/30/23 05:12:38.38 A   2
1   3/30/23 05:12:40.40 A   3
1   3/30/23 05:12:42.42 A   4
1   3/30/23 05:12:44.44 A   4
1   3/30/23 12:12:50.50 B   3
1   3/30/23 12:12:52.52 B   4
1   3/30/23 12:12:54.54 B   5
1   3/30/23 12:12:56.56 B   6
1   3/30/23 12:12:58.58 B   7
1   3/30/23 12:13:00.00 B   8
1   3/30/23 12:13:02.02 B   9
1   3/31/23 20:02:02.02 C   3
1   3/31/23 20:02:05.05 C   4

The Date_Time is pandas datetime object.
I'd like to group the records by Pass_ID, and then select out only those unique Pass_IDs that occur between specific hours in the day: for instance, between 10:00 and 13:00 would return B.
I don't know how to get groupby and 'between_time' to work in this case... which would seem to be the best way forward. I've also tried using a lambda function after setting the Date_Time as the index, but that didn't work. And using aggregate doesn't seem to allow me to pull out the dt.hour of the Date_Time field. Anyone know how to do this concisely?

Try:
# to datetime if necessary
# df["Date_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_Time"])

out = df.set_index("Date_Time").between_time("10:00", "13:00")["Pass_ID"].unique()
print(out)

Prints:
['B']


OR: If you want to filter whole groups between time 10:00-13:00:
out = (
    df.groupby("Pass_ID")
    .filter(
        lambda x: len(x.set_index("Date_Time").between_time("10:00", "13:00")) == len(x)
    )["Pass_ID"]
    .unique()
)
print(out)


Thanks! The later is exactly what I was looking for: ensuring both the start and end dates are within the time for any given "Pass_ID".

Since you times are on the hour you can also use Series.dt.hour.between to create a boolean indexing column, then apply a fast groupby(…).transform('all') to mark groups whose timestamps are all between those hours.
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO('''
index   Date_Time   Pass_ID  El
0   3/30/23 05:12:36.36  A   1
1   3/30/23 05:12:38.38  A   2
1   3/30/23 05:12:40.40  A   3
1   3/30/23 05:12:42.42  A   4
1   3/30/23 05:12:44.44  A   4
1   3/30/23 12:12:50.50  B   3
1   3/30/23 12:12:52.52  B   4
1   3/30/23 12:12:54.54  B   5
1   3/30/23 12:12:56.56  B   6
1   3/30/23 12:12:58.58  B   7
1   3/30/23 12:13:00.00  B   8
1   3/30/23 12:13:02.02  B   9
1   3/31/23 20:02:02.02  C   3
1   3/31/23 20:02:05.05  C   4
'''.strip())

import pandas as pd
df = (
    pd.read_table(buffer, sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
    .assign(
        Date_Time=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['Date_Time'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        btwn=lambda d: d['Date_Time'].dt.hour.between(10, 13).groupby(d['Pass_ID']).transform('all'),
    )
)

print(
    df,
    #     index               Date_Time Pass_ID  El   btwn
    # 0       0 2023-03-30 05:12:36.360       A   1  False
    # 1       1 2023-03-30 05:12:38.380       A   2  False
    # 2       1 2023-03-30 05:12:40.400       A   3  False
    # 3       1 2023-03-30 05:12:42.420       A   4  False
    # 4       1 2023-03-30 05:12:44.440       A   4  False
    # 5       1 2023-03-30 12:12:50.500       B   3   True
    # 6       1 2023-03-30 12:12:52.520       B   4   True
    # 7       1 2023-03-30 12:12:54.540       B   5   True
    # 8       1 2023-03-30 12:12:56.560       B   6   True
    # 9       1 2023-03-30 12:12:58.580       B   7   True
    # 10      1 2023-03-30 12:13:00.000       B   8   True
    # 11      1 2023-03-30 12:13:02.020       B   9   True
    # 12      1 2023-03-31 20:02:02.020       C   3  False
    # 13      1 2023-03-31 20:02:05.050       C   4  False

    df.loc[lambda d: d['btwn']],
    #     index               Date_Time Pass_ID  El  btwn
    # 5       1 2023-03-30 12:12:50.500       B   3  True
    # 6       1 2023-03-30 12:12:52.520       B   4  True
    # 7       1 2023-03-30 12:12:54.540       B   5  True
    # 8       1 2023-03-30 12:12:56.560       B   6  True
    # 9       1 2023-03-30 12:12:58.580       B   7  True
    # 10      1 2023-03-30 12:13:00.000       B   8  True
    # 11      1 2023-03-30 12:13:02.020       B   9  True

    sep='\n\n',
)

